# Calculate Skin HSV values in an image in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am working on hand detection project. Can anyone help me how can i find skin hsv values in an YCrCb color space image in android studio using openCV.

Comment: there are no HSV values in a YCrCb color space image. please read [ask]

Comment: then how can i find skin hsv values in an rgb image?

Comment: you convert whatever colour space you have to HSV. then sample skin pixels for typical values or search the web. no need to re-invent the wheel